# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

React native fail to install

Version install on windows os

Node js version v17.3.0

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.66.4

> info Reloading app...
> BUNDLE  ./index.js
> error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'transformFile')                                             at
> Bundler.transformFile
> (B:\workA\react\react-native-base\sample\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:48:30)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async Object.transform
> (B:\workA\react\react-native-base\sample\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:101:12)
> at async processModule
> (B:\workA\react\react-native-base\sample\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:137:18)
> at async traverseDependenciesForSingleFile
> (B:\workA\react\react-native-base\sample\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:131:3)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)
> at async initialTraverseDependencies
> (B:\workA\react\react-native-base\sample\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:114:3)
> at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies
> (B:\workA\react\react-native-base\sample\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\DeltaCalculator.js:164:25)
> at async DeltaCalculator.getDelta
> (B:\workA\react\react-native-base\sample\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\DeltaCalculator.js:94:16)
> at a
> babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'transform-inline-environment-variables',
      {
        include: ['IS_REACT_NATIVE'],
      },
    ],
  ],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: ['react-native-paper/babel'],
    },
  },
};
```

metro.config.js

```
module.exports = {   transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),   }, };
```